# C++ smart pointer to external managed (e.g: Python) resources?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

Is there a smart pointer in C++ to a resource managed by others?  I am using pybind11 to wrap C++ code as followed.

```c++
    class B {};
    class A {
      public:
        // original C++ class interface
        A(std::shared_ptr<B> pb) : mb(pb){}
        // have to add this for pybind11, since pybind11 doesn't take shared_ptr as argument.
        A(B * pb):A(std::shared_ptr<B>(pb)){}
      private:
        std::shared_ptr<B> mb;
    }
    namespace py = pybind11;
    PYBIND11_MODULE(test, m)
    {
       py::class_<B>(m, "B")
       .def(py::init<>());

       py::class_<A>(m, "A")
       .def(py::init<B *>());
    }
```

Then in python, I'll use them as followed:

```python
    b = B()
    a = A(b)
```

This is fine as long as I don't del a. When I del a in python, the shared_ptr mb I created in C++'s 'A' will try to destroy B object, which is managed by Python and crash. So, my question is if there is some smart pointer in C++ that don't take ownership from a raw pointer? weak_ptr won't work because I'll still have to create a shared_ptr.

Comment: If the smart pointer didn't take ownership in some way, what would you expect its behaviour to be?

Comment: You can use a custom deleter that does nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pybind11 is using a unique pointer behind the scenes to manage the C++ object as it thinks it owns the object, and should deallocate the object whenever the Python wrapper object is deallocated. However, you are sharing this pointer with other parts of the C++ code base. As such, you need to make the Python wrapper of the B class to manage the instance of B using a shared pointer. You can do this in the with `class_` template. eg.

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(test, m)
{
   py::class_<B, std::shared_ptr<B> >(m, "B")
   .def(py::init<>());

   py::class_<A>(m, "A")
   .def(py::init<std::shared_ptr<B> >());
}
```

https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/smart_ptrs.html#std-shared-ptr

Comment: Thanks, your solution works well.  I tried to delete 'b' and object 'a' can still access its internal saved 'mb' without any problem.