# Increase ref_count of pybind11 handle in C++

Tags: python, pybind11

I have a virtual object that I subclass and implement in python using pybind11, and that object then is used in C++ code but the python object goes out of scope when the python script finished and python garbage collector destroys my object before I can use it in C++ side.

To avoid the destruction I have added a "keep" method to the binding code that increases the ref_count, so that python garbage collector doesn't destroy it.

C++ code for the bindings

```
VNCS::Real VNCS::py::BlendingField::blending(const VNCS::Point_3 &p) const
{
    std::array<double, 3> pyP{p[0], p[1], p[2]};
    PYBIND11_OVERLOAD_PURE(VNCS::Real,          /* Return type */
                           VNCS::BlendingField, /* Parent class */
                           blending,            /* Name of function in C++ (must match Python name) */
                           pyP                  /* Argument(s) */
    );
}

void VNCS::py::module::blendingField(pybind11::module &m)
{
    pybind11::class_<VNCS::BlendingField, VNCS::py::BlendingField, std::shared_ptr<VNCS::BlendingField>>(
        m, "BlendingField")
        .def(pybind11::init(
            [](pybind11::args &args, pybind11::kwargs &kwargs) { return std::make_shared<VNCS::py::BlendingField>(); }))
        .def("keep", [](pybind11::handle handle) { handle.inc_ref(); });
}
```

Python code

```
class BlendingField(PyVNCS.BlendingField):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      PyVNCS.BlendingField.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

   def __del__(self):
       print("dtor from python")

   def blending(self, point):
       return point[0]

blendingField = BlendingField()
blendingField.keep()
simCreator = initObject.addObject("SimCreator",
                     name="simCreator",
                     coarseMesh="@lowResTopology",
                     detailMesh="@highResTopology")
simCreator.setBlendingField(blendingField)
```

This doesn't look very nice, as the `keep` method there feels like a terrible hack. What would be the correct way to implement this?

Comment: What is `initObject` and `setBlendingField`? I would expect that the python garbage collector shouldn't destroy the object if it's passed in to `setBlendingField`.

Comment: initObject is an object from another library, sofa. It creates a SimCreator object. Then I set the blendingField on the SimCreator, but after that script is called, the blending field is used from C++, but it has been freed (console actually shows "dtor from python") and I have an error if I dont increase the reference count manually

Answer (score 0):

I don't think messing with the ref count is the best solution. If you want to use an object in C++-land, use C++ lifetime management tools.

Pybind integrates lifetime management into the language bindings, you just need to change it's behavior. To quote the  [docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/smart_ptrs.html):

> The binding generator for classes, `class_`, can be passed a template type that denotes a special holder type that is used to manage references to the object. If no such holder type template argument is given, the default for a type named Type is `std::unique_ptr<Type>`, which means that the object is deallocated when Python’s reference count goes to zero.
>
> It is possible to switch to other types of reference counting wrappers or smart pointers, which is useful in codebases that rely on them. For instance, the following snippet causes `std::shared_ptr` to be used instead.

Here's an example lifted from the [tests](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/tests/test_smart_ptr.cpp):

```cpp
// Object managed by a std::shared_ptr<>
class MyObject2 {
public:
    MyObject2(const MyObject2 &) = default;
    MyObject2(int value) : value(value) { print_created(this, toString()); }
    std::string toString() const { return "MyObject2[" + std::to_string(value) + "]"; }
    virtual ~MyObject2() { print_destroyed(this); }
private:
    int value;
};
py::class_<MyObject2, std::shared_ptr<MyObject2>>(m, "MyObject2")
    .def(py::init<int>());
m.def("make_myobject2_1", []() { return new MyObject2(6); });
m.def("make_myobject2_2", []() { return std::make_shared<MyObject2>(7); });
m.def("print_myobject2_1", [](const MyObject2 *obj) { py::print(obj->toString()); });
m.def("print_myobject2_2", [](std::shared_ptr<MyObject2> obj) { py::print(obj->toString()); });
m.def("print_myobject2_3", [](const std::shared_ptr<MyObject2> &obj) { py::print(obj->toString()); });
m.def("print_myobject2_4", [](const std::shared_ptr<MyObject2> *obj) { py::print((*obj)->toString()); });
```

If you do go that route, which I would recommend, this question would be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53786965/c-smart-pointer-to-external-managed-e-g-python-resources).

Note that there are some minor pitfalls here especially if youre codebase uses raw pointers around python code. The docs point to a possible double-free if a C++ method returning a raw pointer to an shared object is called from python. Again stealing from the [docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/smart_ptrs.html):

```cpp
class Child { };

class Parent {
public:
   Parent() : child(std::make_shared<Child>()) { }
   Child *get_child() { return child.get(); }  /* Hint: ** DON'T DO THIS ** */
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Child> child;
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    py::class_<Child, std::shared_ptr<Child>>(m, "Child");

    py::class_<Parent, std::shared_ptr<Parent>>(m, "Parent")
       .def(py::init<>())
       .def("get_child", &Parent::get_child);
}
```

```py
from example import Parent
print(Parent().get_child()) // UB or Segfault
```

Though these issue don't seem to me to be unique to `shared_ptr` over `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Ill have a look. Im still learning pybind11 and learning it. Ill test it asap!

Comment: I actually feel like this is somehow polluting my C++ code side with implementation details from the python bindings. From the C++ perspective, I need a ptr to the BlendingField to call the virtual function, but the std::shared_ptr its something required by the binding. Other users could use the SimCreator and the BlendingField only from C++, and it wont make sense to have a shared_ptr there. This is probably open to discussion, I would like to heard your opinion about it.

Comment: I have tested this and it doesn't work. The issue is that the python part of the derived class is deleted. I get "dtor from python" in the console, meaning that the BlendingField implemented in python is being destroyed.

Comment: Apparently this is an open issue on pybind11 with several reported issues on github. Ill close it